# How to invoke the method fun of an abstract class in the following code?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am trying to figure out how to call the method fun of an abstract class by a derived class object?
Could you please spent sometime to help me out.

```
class A {
    void fun (){
        System.out.println("In A");
    }
}


      // An abstract class with a final method
abstract class Base extends A {
    void fun(){
        System.out.println("Base fun() called");
    }
}



class Derived extends Base {
    void fun(){
        System.out.println("Derived fun() called");
    }
}
```

Glad to receive an answer

Comment: Please go through and *study* the [help] and the [ask] to see what is expected of questions posted to this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is for the `fun()` method of `Derived` to call the `Base` version of `fun()` internally, then put `super.fun()` somewhere in the `Derived` class's `fun()` method. Similarly, the `fun()` method of `Base` can use `super.fun()` to invoke the `fun()` method of `A`.

What you cannot do is, for an object of class `Derived`, "skip past" the `Derived` implementation of `fun()` and instead invoke the overridden `Base` or `A` version of `fun()`.